# What is Creo Normalizer JTP?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Can anyone provide any useful links/information about a piece of software called **Creo Normalizer JTP**? I think it's a PDF generation tool, perhaps built into high-end scanners or something, but this is mainly a guess.

The reason I ask is that I am troubleshooting a problem with `pdf2swf` and that is the only piece of information I have for the time being! For information, pdf2swf's return code is 1, but I have no other information apart from:

```
Producer:     Creo Normalizer JTP
```

Google searches only provide links to (often dodgy) download sites, which I'm not able to access through my employer's firewall.

Thanks in advance!

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JTP is a Job Ticket Processor. I believe a job ticket describes some kind of transformation to a file including a number of input parameters that can control the processors behaviour. A JTP generally forms part of a larger workflow that can consist of processors such as Copydot, Trap, Thumbnail, Normalize, Color Convert, Optimize, Impose.

Prinergy is a prepress workflow system created by Creo. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prinergy) gives a bit more information about the different processors and this [document](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:T7UsEgY9JIoJ:www.creo.com/data/Partners/workflow/Files/Connecting_Prinergy_Nov1.pdf+jtp+creo&hl=en&gl=au&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESintBrNWPay14GWu3fRVsMUXVJ97Rsz3Tr6LJoOxqXomnr5UIlYJFKuM3OJNoUoLp9z6BOSVWGI2Ett1FCZBzTeacQZxUQ3hXcjAOHsw7I4taq6Oixc6gm1cbrom8VC_hc8YZOu&sig=AHIEtbS4VYrBM9UdoJcxrgn4cyfMIkw5gg) shows the configuration of a workflow. The Normalizer typically converts from EPS or PS formats to PDF.

Creo possibly license their JTPs to other software vendors. I'd say your best bet would be to get in contact with Creo to find out the meaning of the return code if that's what you are trying to decipher.